# including post-specific feed without full wp_head()

Tags: theme-development

I'm not including the wp_head() call in my header.php, but I would like to include the feed links for each post.

Is it possible to call wp_head() with arguments only to include specific functionality? Or alternately, can you call specific functionality (admin toolbar css, feed links, etc) directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all `wp_head()` does is run all the actions attached to it:

```
function wp_head() {
    do_action('wp_head');
}
```

you can call `get_feed_link()` directly.

however -

it's important to note you're going to break most plugins by not calling `wp_head()` a better route may be to just `remove_action` on all the things you *don't* want in `wp_head()`. look in `wp-includes/default-filters.php` for all the actions attached to it.